# How to record video in portrait on android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-video-player

I have an application where the the user can record video. The app is designed to be used in portrait. The camera preview is fine however when I watch the video back is is rotated to the side.I know you cannot modify the camera stream, and the way you could do it is to  rotate the video after which would be a heavy task. I was asking do you know how the standard android camera gets around this, on the normal camera you can record portrait and the recorded video is portrait.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465835/camera-picture-orientation-in-android ? From your question I couldn't understand if you are currently recording in portrait or not. "however when I watch the video back" means that the preview is ok but opening the video after it is recorded, the image is rotated? did you save the video and watched it in other device?

Comment: Yer this question is a follow up mostly. Im currently recording in portrait, and it previews fine while recording, however on the same device through a video view or gallery it plays landscape ( 90 degrees anti-clockwise) I accept you can't change the camera, but I was wondering do you know how the standard android camera avoids this problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you mean but you can try to force the opposite orientation on your "camera preview" to see how that works. It might record it as you like and then you have your solution.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the camera preview works fine its the recorded video which is still rotated which from what I understand isn't affected by the camera preview

Comment: you might be right. i cant find anything about it in the documentations for now. have you tried it though if it makes a difference? Otherwise it might simply depend on the device you are using how the video is being saved and on the player you are playing it with. There might not be something general about it.