# Camera issue in portrait view

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using Android's default camera in my application. After taking a photo I show it in an image view. When the photo is taken in landscape mode, it appears in image view as it should, but when the same photo is taken in portrait view, it is rotated 90 degree. Is it possible to detect the camera mode (landscape or portrait) through the code?

Comment: Did you look at [Camera.setDisplayOrientation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)) ? Or this one: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation%28int%29

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465835/camera-picture-orientation-in-android ?